# changing an icon to another icon on a header of a webapp

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a webapp using jquery mobile and I would like to be able to change the right hand side icon when I click on it for another icon. for example, I have an audio file embedded inTO the code that has the attribute "autoplay" so it starts as soon as the page loads but I would like to click on the volume-mute icon and have it changed into a mute icon with the crossed sign letting the users know that there's a way to click on and off of it to listen to the background sound. If any of you have any idea I could achieve something like this. it'll be grealy appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking about a listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/qp3bQ/1/

Try to click right side volume icon.

### JQUERY

```
$('#volume').on('click', function(){
    var name = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
    if (name == 'http://www.flaticon.com/png/256/498.png')
        $(this).children('img').attr('src','http://www.flaticon.com/png/256/8785.png');
    else
        $(this).children('img').attr('src','http://www.flaticon.com/png/256/498.png');
});
```

Comment: Hello Yeyene, thank you for providing the right code on how to achieve this. This is exactly what I needed. I have already implemented it into my application and it works perfectly!!! just before I go and accept your answer, wanted to ask if you know about any website source or links where you can get mobile oriented code snippets to give more life to apps and make them more dinamic for user experience purposes.

Comment: Check JQM (http://jquerymobile.com/), old version demo (http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/buttons/), latest flat version demo (http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/button-markup/)